# force android app to send a whatsapp message

Tags: android, whatsapp

I try to send a WhatsApp message through my android app. 
I have used the example on WhatsApp docu site and add some extras in it.
It works well but it just opens WA and puts my text into the input field.

Now the question is, how can I send the message without clicking on send button in WA?

There are many examples on the internet which just get you to the input filed in WA but there is no example or explanation how to send the message automatically.

I do not know if that's allowed at all from WA.

Is there someone who has a solution for this problem.

And please do not send any examples that just fill out the input field on WA, i have done this already.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is allowed by WhatsApp.

On the developer website they mention this:

> There are two ways to integrate with WhatsApp:
>
> -Through a custom URL scheme
>
> -Through Android's intent system.

See: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012

Comment: yes I have already used that, actually both of them, but they both just open WA and put my text into the input field but they do not send it. :(